# Is it normal for "autovacuum" and "COMMIT" to always be top contributors to load in RDS postgresql performance insights?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Whenever I go to the "Performance Insights" console for an RDS postgresql instance, there are always two entries making up most of the "load by waits (average active sessions)": `autovacuum` and `COMMIT`.

[image]

Is this normal, or should I be doing something about it?

It is suggested in an answer that the high COMMIT load may be due to the disk being overloaded. I assume that some cloudwatch metrics may support this, but I am unsure what is normal here too.

DiskQueueDepth (maximum per hour, over a week):

[image]

WriteLatency (maximum per hour, over a week):

[image]

ReadLatency never gets about 0.002s, so I assume this is not a problem.

CPU IO/wait is of interest; here is (I think) a graph of that from Performance Insights. It peaks at around 6% in the previous 24 hrs (I think this may be a 5 minute average):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `COMMIT` consumes substantial time, that is usually a sure sign for I/O overload.

But in your case all the evidence speaks against that. Since I don't know what exactly the graph measures, I would say that what you observe is a moderately busy OLTP system with lots of small write operations.

If you want to reduce the work during `COMMIT`, you could set `synchronous_commit` to `off`. The price you would be paying is that you can lose up to 0.6 seconds of committed transactions in the case of a crash.

Comment: I added some hopefully relevant disk-related cloudwatch metrics to my question.

Comment: Added IO wait graph - peaks around 6%. Also, thanks for prompting me to discover some new metrics in performance insights (as well as helping me with the problem overall).

Comment: All interaction with the DB is via vanilla rails/active record, so I doubt there's anything like you suggest being used.

I should clarify that there's no performance problem as such (e.g. noticeably impacting users) - just that I see the `COMMIT` line sitting near the top of load list and I wonder if that's bad or nothing to worry about.

> Did you experience the problem at the time covered by the graph

But to answer this:  yes, `COMMIT` is always there near the top in performance insights.

Comment: I have reconsidered and changed my answer.